# Can't access cd rom - files unreadable

Tags: data-recovery, compact-disc

I am trying to access a cd which I have burnt in the past. I am currently unable to access the files on the disk. In the Windows Explorer I am able to see file names and sizes.

I have tried "CDcheck" from http://www.kvipu.com/CDCheck/download.php to recover the disc but it doesn't seem to get one clean read of a sector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this tool: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Pretty much works out of the box and recovered a good amount of data for completly free :)
Enjoy. Hope I saved someone asome work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your CD is going to be unreadable.

Comment: http://www.infinadyne.com/cddvd_diagnostic.html just tried this seems to work but pay only :(